# Facebook Tagged photos in android -> facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, api

I am using the facebook api to do an android application. It asks the user to select friends to see tagged photos. (That is if the user selects two names A and B -> he should be able to see A and B in one photo). To do this pragmatically, I user the graph api explorer but finding it difficult to come up with the request call. Please refer the image:

[image: facebook api explorer]

For my query, above information should be used. That is, I need to get "picture" when I supply "id(userID)"..

Please tell me how this has to be done!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me . Do you actually want to post an image with tagged friends or you simply want to add friends in an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are five steps involved with this:

step 1:

Login to Facebook:

```
private void loginToFacebook()
       {
           mPrefs = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
           accessToken = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
           long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

           if (accessToken != null)
           {
               facebook.setAccessToken(accessToken);
               uploadPhoto(facebook, imageBitmap, null);
           }

           if (expires != 0)
           {
               facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
           }

           if (!facebook.isSessionValid())
           {
            facebook.authorize(activity, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();                        
                            uploadPhoto(facebook, imageBitmap, null);                   
                    }

                    public void onCancel() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

           }
       }
```

Step 2:

Upload the image to Facebook (bitmap is uploaded), note that this method is called within the login method. FOllowing method returns the ID of the uploaded image, so this is needed when tagging friends:

```
public  String uploadPhoto(Facebook facebook, Bitmap image, String albumId)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            if ( albumId == null ) {
                albumId = "me";
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] photoBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
            params.putByteArray("picture", photoBytes);

            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                String resp = facebook.request(albumId + "/photos", params, "POST");
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(resp);
                if(json.getString("id") != null){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Image Successfully uploaded to facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    tagFriends();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploading failed, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                uploadedImageID = json.getString("id");
                return json.getString("id");

            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploading failed, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch ( FacebookError e ) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploading failed, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch ( JSONException e ) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploading failed, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            return null;
        }
```

Step 3:

Get all friends of your facebook account and store in a hash map:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);   
                mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends" , params , "GET", new RequestListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.d("InviteFriends.inviteFriends().new RequestListener() {...}:onComplete", "FB Response =>"+ responseJsonObject);
                            //event_id = event.getString("id");


                            //JSONObject responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(eventResponse);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = responseJsonObject.getJSONArray("data");


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                map.put("id",    e.getString("id"));
                                map.put("name",  e.getString("name"));
                                mylist.add(map);

                                userIds = e.getString("id");
                                userName = e.getString("name");
                                Log.d("MainActivity:getAllEvents", "Friend ID, Name:" +  userIds + "," + userName);

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        }
```

Step 4:

Show the list of names in a listview and capture the user IDs of the user names that the user touches from the list and store them in an array:

```
final ListView friends = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.lst_frnds);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mylist , R.layout.friends_main,  new String[] {"name" }, new int[] {R.id.item_title});
                                Log.d( "size","Friends->" + mylist.size());
friends.setAdapter(adapter);
friends.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                                    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                                        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) friends.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                        String selectedName = o.get("name");
                                        String selectedId = o.get("id");
                                        Toast.makeText(MemeList.this, "Your friend " + selectedName + "' was selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        selectedFriendsIDs.add(selectedId);
                                        selectedFriendsNames.add(selectedName);
}
```

Step 5:

Tag selected friends from the list:

```
btnSendInvites.setText(selectedFriendsIDs.size() + " selected, tag them now?");



                                        btnSendInvites.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                //Tagging friends 
                                                for(int i = 0; i < selectedFriendsIDs.size(); i++){

                                                    String inputParm = uploadedImageID + "/tags?to=" + selectedFriendsIDs.get(i);

                                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                                    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);   
                                                    mAsyncRunner.request(inputParm, params, "POST", new RequestListener()
                                                    {

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
                                                        {

                                                        }

                                                        public void onIOException1(IOException e, Object state)
                                                        {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
                                                        {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
                                                        {

                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                                                        {
                                                            Log.d("Selected IDs ", "" + selectedFriendsIDs);
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
                                                        {
                                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                                        }
                                                    }, null);
                                                }


                                            }
                                        });
```

If successfully tagged, will return true.

Hope this helps someone!